# angular-csv-import not working on ionic

Tags: angularjs, csv, ionic-framework

I am trying to use [angular-csv-import](https://github.com/bahaaldine/angular-csv-import) on ionic. all works greate on chrome but when I am trying to run it on android nothing is happens...file manager to upload the file isnt working....what can be done?

my code is:
template:

```
   <ng-csv-import content="csv.content"
               header="csv.header"
               separator="csv.separator"
               result="csv.result"
               accept="csv.accept">
</ng-csv-import>
```

controller:

```
  $scope.csv = {
      content: null,
      header: true,
      headerVisible: true,
      separator: ',',
      separatorVisible: true,
      result: null,
      encoding: 'ISO-8859-1',
      encodingVisible: true,
      accept: ".csv"
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find 2 ways to do it.
One way to save the document from google shits and get plugin to parse it to json, then use ng to download parsed json. Or the other way to use [xlsx parser](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx)